# Can't Bind member of anObject with a Textblock via x:Bind

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

obl.name binded with TextBlock .
Code in XAML

```
<StackPanel Background="Gray" Orientation="Vertical">
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind obl.name, Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="Aquamarine" />
<Button Content="click" Click="Button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Code in .Cs File

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        obl = new Class1();
        DataContext = obl;
    }
    public Class1 obl { get; set; }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        obl.name = "haiiii";
    }
```

class1

```
public class Class1
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Binded value doesnot appears in UI. why ?

Comment: `Text="{x:Bind name}"`. How could the XAML possibly know the name of a local variable in a method somewhere? You assigned that object to DataContext. The DataContext is where bindings look for properties. You tell a binding, "bind to `name`", and it looks for `name` on the DataContext.

Comment: And you don't need `Mode=TwoWay` because a TextBlock can't write a value back to the source.

Comment: First you need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface.Then it should work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind some text in property that the `class1` must implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and set the property changed.

```
public class Class1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;

    public string name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

But as the property, the property `name` should be named as `Name` for PascalCasing.

Thx @thezapper